# trigger to hide and show table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to trigger a hide and a show on my  table `local starTable = {}`

```
local starTable = {} -- Set up star table


local function showStarTable()
-- some trigger to show the star table
end
timer.performWithDelay( 500, showStarTable, 1 )

local function hideStarTable()
-- some trigger to hide the star table
end
timer.performWithDelay( 1000, hideStarTable, 1 )
```

Is it possible to achieve this

Comment: What kind of elements starTable contains ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go along with the first answer here is an example:

```
local starTable = {}
local star1  = <display object>


starTable:insert(star1)

local function showStarTable()
    starTable.alpha = 1
end
timer.performWithDelay( 500, showStarTable, 1 )


local function hideStarTable()
    starTable.alpha = 0
end
timer.performWithDelay( 1000, hideStarTable, 1 )
```

Or of you wanted to stick with an actual table. and without seeing what actually is inserted into your starTable you could try:

```
local starTable = {}

local star  = <display object>
starTable[1] = star

star  = <display object>
starTable[2] = star

star  = <display object>
starTable[3] = star

local function showStarTable()
    for i=1, #starTable do
        starTable[i].star.alpha = 1
    end
end
timer.performWithDelay( 500, showStarTable, 1 )


local function hideStarTable()
    for i=1, #starTable do
        starTable[i].star.alpha = 0
    end
end
timer.performWithDelay( 1000, hideStarTable, 1 )
```

However, the first option is better, if it works with your program.

Comment: I just noticed a typo in my post the first line of the first group of code should say "local starTable = display.newGroup()"

Answer (score 1):

Your code will execute the function showStarTable() after 1/2 second for 1 time.   Then in another 1/2 second, it will execute hideStarTable() once.

Display objects like display.newImageRect() are tables, so if that's the table you are referring to, you can show/hide them by changing either the .alpha property of the object or it's visibility (.isVisible = true or .isVisible = false).  However tables by themselves are just containers of information and a generic table isn't displayable.  It could contain a single display object ore multiple.

It would be your responsibility in your show/hide functions to show/hide the contents of the table, if the table has displayable content.